# create an element once for several click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a div with a class (only one). It has to open each time the details are expanded, but the div is created at each click...

Here is the HTML

```
<main>
    <section>
        <h3>title</h3>

        <div>
            <details>
                <summary>sum1</summary>
                content1
            </details>

            <details>
                <summary>sum2</summary>
                content2
            </details>
        </div>

    </section>
</main>
```

And here the JS

```
$('.firstContent').hide();

$('details').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("openedDetails");
    $('details').not(this).removeAttr("open");
    $('details').not(this).removeClass("openedDetails");

    if ($('details').hasClass('openedDetails')) {
        $('section h3').after('<div class="firstContent">content3</div>');
        $('.firstContent').show();
    } else {
        $('.firstContent').hide();
    }

});
```

EDIT : With the toggleClass system (I think it's a better way), the .firstContent div is created directly in HTML between h3 and the next div

```
$('.firstContent').hide();
$('main details').click(function(){
    var mainSelf = $(this);
    $(mainSelf).toggleClass('openedDetails');
    $('details').not(mainSelf).removeAttr('open');
    $('details').not(mainSelf).removeClass('openedDetails');

    var mainParent = $(mainSelf).parents('main');
    mainParent.addClass('mainParent');
    $('main').not(mainParent).removeClass('mainParent');

    var openedFirst = $('.firstContent', mainParent);
    openedFirst.addClass('openedFirst');
    $('.firstContent').not(openedFirst).removeClass('openedFirst');
    openedFirst.show();
    $('.firstContent').not(openedFirst).hide();

});
```

Comment: Why are you _creating_ the element, instead of toggling its display? Creating, destroying, creating, destroying, etc., is additional work on the DOM that doesn't immediately appear to be necessary.

Comment: I know how to do it with toggleClass, but wanted to try by creating elements, just for improve my skills in jquery (that's a kind of experience I guess, thanks for your help ;) )

Comment: Props to you for trying to sharpen your skills; but the approach you're taking is not ideal for the project you're working on. Just my two cents 

Comment: I got it, thank you for your advices, I edit my post, maybe it's better, maybe not, but I'm trying ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `remove()` instead of `hide()`, because you are basically adding a new `firstContent` div with every click, without removing the previous one. You are just **hiding** it.

```js
$('.firstContent').hide();

$('details').click(function () {
$('.firstContent').remove();
    $(this).toggleClass("openedDetails");
    $('details').not(this).removeAttr("open");
    $('details').not(this).removeClass("openedDetails");

    if ($('details').hasClass('openedDetails')) {
        $('section h3').after('<div class="firstContent">content3</div>');
        $('.firstContent').show();
    } else {
        $('.firstContent').remove();
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
    <section>
        <h3>title</h3>

        <div>
            <details>
                <summary>sum1</summary>
                content1
            </details>

            <details>
                <summary>sum2</summary>
                content2
            </details>
        </div>

    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Code creates a glitch

Comment: @JoséphFlames What do you mean by 'glitch'?

Comment: If you run the snippet content 3 and content 1 go to the outsides of the div and duplicate

Comment: @JoséphFlames Thank you my friend for it. Fixed.

Comment: I didn't know how to use the .remove() method, well, now I know, thanks for your help ;)